# Compose for RabbitMq coonection issue from IBM cloud app

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, ibm-cloud

I have created a compose for RabbitMq instance in IBM cloud and I'm using it through service binding on my config server application. My `application.yaml` has the below properties defined to connect to the compose for rabbitmq server:

```
 spring:
 profiles: config-monitor
 cloud:
     bus:
         enabled: true
 rabbitmq:
      addresses: amqps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@portal-ssl12-36.bmix-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.composedb.com:58288/vhost-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Also, with the service binding, environment variables were updated with VCAP credentials for RabbitMQ.

Maven dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

The issue is on startup I get connection exceptions for RabbitMq Service:

> o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin : Failed to declare exchange: Exchange [name=springCloudBus, type=topic, durable=true, autoDelete=false, internal=false, arguments={}], continuing...
>
> c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler : An unexpected connection driver error occured java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed

As follows:

```
2018-09-24 17:51:50.646 ERROR 19140 --- [.46.29.90:58547] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occured
java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
2018-09-24 17:51:50.647 DEBUG 19140 --- [           main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Failed to declare exchange: Exchange [name=springCloudBus, type=topic, durable=true, autoDelete=false, internal=false, arguments={}], continuing...
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:74) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:371) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:573) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareExchange(RabbitAdmin.java:157) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.provisioning.RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner.declareExchange(RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner.java:412) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.provisioning.RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner.java:90) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.provisioning.RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner.java:58) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:110) [spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:57) [spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) [spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:124) [spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238) [spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57) [spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at aa.ct.fly.config.server.ConfigServer.main(ConfigServer.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
 at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:372) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:297) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:909) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:352) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I do not have any other special code yet to create exchanges/ queues etc.

Any idea why it should fail with connection issues between an application deployed in ibm-cloud and the rabbitmq service which is also provisioned by ibm-cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot uses amqp protocol to connect to RabbitMQ while Compose services on IBM Cloud are exposed through a HAProxy as amqps.

On my case I changed the connection URI directly on rabbitConnectionFactory by creating a @Configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class MessagingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(RabbitProperties config) throws Exception {

        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setUri(RABBITMQ_ADDRESS);

        return connectionFactory;

    }

}
```

You can also use your VCAP variable on application.yml file and inject on configuration bean using the Spring Boot @Value annotation.